# mysqli_real_escape_string and stripslashes returning blank variables

Tags: php, mysqli, stripslashes

I am using the following code to clean any variables that get returned from forms. I recently swapped over from mysql to mysqli but as a result the function below is now stripping my variables back to being blank.

```
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('config.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysqli_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysqli_select_db($link,DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$login = clean($_POST['login']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);

//Input Validations
if($login == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: login-form.php");
    exit();
}
```

So every time I type in a valid username and password it redirects me back to the login page saying that both fields were in fact blank. The moment I remove the 'clean' function around the POST values it starts working again.

I'm new to mysqli however I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: You should check [mysqli_connect_errno](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php).

Comment: Same problem still. Once I get rid of the clean function everything works fine so the database connection is correct (although I will still keep that change as it's helpful, but it doesn't solve my problem)

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't show your DB info.
2. Try to do:

   ```
   mysql_real_escape_string
   ```

Comment: If I switch back to using mysql then I have to switch all other examples of mysqli on the page back to mysql as well. And people have been telling me for months to stop using mysql as it's deprecated.